# Excel dynamic formula with SUMPRODUCT and OFFSET

Tags: excel-formula, dynamic, range, offset, sumproduct

I have 3 columns in excel:

- column P is a range of numbers starting from 1 until 11, then from 1 until 14 and so on, it is never the same number of rows
- column W has numbers that are dependent on column P
- column AK has numbers that are dependent on column P

The issue is that the formula I am using doesn't sumproduct the entire range from column P - meaning the whole set from 1 to 11, next 1 to 14, and so on.

This is the formula I am using:

```
=+SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(W2;0;0;MATCH(1;P:P;0));OFFSET(AK2;0;0;MATCH(1;P:P;0)))/AK2, and the MATCH part always returns 2, meaning it takes just the 2 numbers not the entire range from 1 to 11, then 1 to 14.
```

[image]

Column P is the one coloured and then columns W and AK which need the sumproduct on. The idea is that it needs to sumproduct from 1 to 11 and then from 1 to 14, and the range to always decrease as it advances from 1 to 11, and at 11 to be just one input.

Comment: Do you want to apply SUMPRODUCT to two ranges each with 25 numbers in them. If so, is it always 25 numbers? If not always 25 then is there anything else in columns W and AK that prevents just using the whole of each column?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant to calculate:
`=+SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET(W2,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH(1,(P:P=1)*(ROW(P:P)>ROW()),0),1+LOOKUP(2,1/P:P,ROW(P:P)))-ROW()),OFFSET(AK2,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH(1,(P:P=1)*(ROW(P:P)>ROW()),0),1+LOOKUP(2,1/P:P,ROW(P:P)))-ROW()))/AK2`

The `MATCH(1;P:P;0)` part of your formula will search for the value `1` stfarting from row 1 and will always find it in the second row (first occurence), therefore we need to declare to find the first 1 where the row number is greater than the current. Because this will lead to an error at the last sequence that does not have a `1` to find anywhere after each value. We therefore use an iferror to return the last row number.

However the above works I wouldn't recommend using it. OFFSET is a volatile function that recalculates at **any** change within the workbook **anywhere**.
This will lead to a slow file, which is annoying. Therefore use INDEX instead of OFFSET:

`=SUMPRODUCT(W2:INDEX(W:W,IFERROR(MATCH(1,(P:P=1)*(ROW(P:P)>ROW()),0)-1,LOOKUP(2,1/P:P,ROW(P:P)))),AK2:INDEX(AK:AK,IFERROR(MATCH(1,(P:P=1)*(ROW(P:P)>ROW()),0)-1,LOOKUP(2,1/P:P,ROW(P:P)))))/AK2`

(replace the colon with semicolon:)
`=SUMPRODUCT(W2:INDEX(W:W;IFERROR(MATCH(1;(P:P=1)*(ROW(P:P)>ROW());0)-1;LOOKUP(2;1/P:P;ROW(P:P))));AK2:INDEX(AK:AK;IFERROR(MATCH(1;(P:P=1)*(ROW(P:P)>ROW());0)-1;LOOKUP(2;1/P:P;ROW(P:P)))))/AK2`

In Office 365 I'd go with something like:

```
=LET(p,P2:P26,w,W2:W26,ak,AK2:AK26,
z,SCAN(0,p,LAMBDA(x,y,x+(y=1))),
DROP(REDUCE(0,UNIQUE(z),LAMBDA(x,y,
LET(f,z=y,
    a,FILTER(p,f),
    b,FILTER(w,f),
    c,FILTER(ak,f),
VSTACK(x,MMULT(N(TOROW(a)>=a),b*c)/c)))),1))
```

Comment: I do have Office 365

Comment: Please see updated answer for an Office 365 solution (This will spill the formula in the size of the inputted ranges `p`, `w` and `ak`.